# react-native: redux store doesn't re-render component unless connected to deeper level

Tags: react-native, redux

I have an object called history which is connected to my redux store.

The connection to store is simple:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  history: state.ressources.history,
}), null)(HistoryComponent)
```

The component resides as a tab of react-navigation and it should re-render when there is a change to the history object in the store.

The object goes deep with nested properties. When a deeper property changes ('stars' in this case), the component doesn't re render unless you specifically connect to this deeper property:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  history: state.ressources.history.tasker.stars,
}), null)(HistoryComponent)
```

When connected like this, the component does re-render. Why doesn't it when connected to simply state.resources.history?

The way the state is updated in the reducer is:

```
  saveRessources = (state, action) => {
    const newState = { ...(_.mergeWith(
      state,
      action.ressources,
      mergeWithCustomizer)),
    }
    return newState
  }

mergeWithCustomizer = (objValue, srcValue) => {
    if (Array.isArray(srcValue)) { return srcValue }

    return undefined
}
```

But the thing is that everything updates successfully, but for the component to re-render why does it have to be connected to a deeper level of the object?

Comment: is it possible to show us some code how you use state inside your component? I see that you don't pass any action to your component at the moment

Comment: It probably is due to how you "update" the state in reducer, so showing that would enable other users to help.

Comment: Hello I edited my question to show how the state is updated. Yes I don't pass any actions, I just use console log to see when it re renders